# How to get matches the value of one column with another column in the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I would like to get the matches from one column with the other columns in a dataframe. Below is an example:

```
  tableNameFrom   tableNameJoin   attributeName
1 film            language        [film.languageId, language.languageID]
2 inventory       rental          [invetory.inventoryId, rental.filmId]
```

In the example above, I would like to match between tablenameFrom and tablenameJoin with the attributeName. Here desired output:

```
  tableName    attributeName
1 film         languageId
2 language     languageID
3 inventory    inventoryId
4 rental       filmId
```

Comment: Edited answer. In SO is not answerer notify, if question is changed, so necessary do it manually - add comment under answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution working only with `attributeName` column, because from sample data there are all data need for output.

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) first by `,`, then reshape `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and split by `.`:

```
df1 = (df['attributeName'].str.split(', ', expand=True)
                          .stack()
                          .str.split('.', expand=True)
                          .reset_index(drop=True))
df1.columns = ['tableName','attributeName']
print (df1)
  tableName attributeName
0      film    languageId
1  language    languageID
2  invetory   inventoryId
3    rental        filmId
```

EDIT:

If values are lists use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print (type(df.loc[1, 'attributeName']))
<class 'list'>

df1 = (pd.DataFrame(df['attributeName'].values.tolist())
                          .stack()
                          .str.split('.', expand=True)
                          .reset_index(drop=True))
df1.columns = ['tableName','attributeName']
print (df1)
  tableName attributeName
0      film    languageId
1  language    languageID
2  invetory   inventoryId
3    rental        filmId
```